# Stackoverflow when use bufferedInputStream as a trait in scala

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to solve a problem given by the Book "Scala for the Impatient", which asked to implement java's BufferedInputStream as a trait. Here is my implementation,

```
trait Buffering {           
    this:InputStream =>
        private[this] val bis = {
            new JavaBufferedInputStream(this)
        }
        override def read = bis.read
        override def read(byte:Array[Byte], off:Int, len:Int) = bis.read(byte, off, len)
        override def available = bis.available
        override def close() {
            bis.close
        }
        override def skip(n:Long) = bis.skip(n)
}

def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val bfis = new FileInputStream(new File("foo.txt")) with Buffering
    println(bfis.read)
    bfis.close
}
```

But this give me a java stackoverflow error, so what's wrong with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a stack overflow where you don't expect one. The key to troubleshoot these is to look at the repeating cycle of the stack trace. It usually points to what is repeatedly allocating frames. Here it will show something like that:

```
at C.Buffering$class.read(C.scala:12)
at C.C$$anon$1.read(C.scala:23)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at C.Buffering$class.read(C.scala:12)
at C.C$$anon$1.read(C.scala:23)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:256)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at C.Buffering$class.read(C.scala:12)
```

So reading from bottom to top, it looks like your `read(byte, ...)` is calling `bis.read(byte, ...)` which is calling `BufferedInputStream.read` which is then calling your `read(byte, ...)` again.

It would appear that `new BufferedInputStream(this)` is calling `read` on the underlying `InputStream` but since the underlying `this` is your object that then delegates calls on `bis` we have infinite recursion.

I'm guessing that the author wants you to use the `abstract override` stackable modifications pattern where you can use `super` to refer to the right `read` method.

Comment: I put some "println" into the execution block of read in Buffering, and confirms "read" is only executed when I call bfis.read. I did notice that read(byte:Array[Byte], off:Int, len:Int) is liking being called in an infinite loop, which I don't understand why... Concerning your suggestion, if I used abstract override to call super, how can I mix BufferedInputStream into the underlying inputStream? Can you shed more light on that? Thanks much!

Comment: @Sheng, `read` is only executed once but then calls `BufferedInputStream.read` which calls `read(Array[Byte], int, int)` which causes infinite loop. The infinite loop is because `BufferedInputStream` is trying to buffer `this` which is to say it is trying to buffered itself... With respect to the abstract override, I don't know. I don't have the book. Does the author suggest you should be using the Java BufferedInputStream? It seems it would be hard to convert it as a mixin since it was not designed that way.

Comment: @huynhjil, I start to believe the intent of this problem is to ask readers to somehow implement their own buffered methods instead of calling the java one (and it is not that difficult, just call super.read to read a big chunk of data into an array buffer to improve reading performance ...), 'cause there is no way to get around that recursive, infinite call-itself trap. Thanks for your abstract override suggestion, I think that is what I need:-)

Comment: There really should be a way to pass `super` (i.e. the instance of `InputStream`) to the constructor of `JavaBufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the answer. Just maybe from what i understood.

```
trait Buffering extends InputStream{
abstract override def read()=
{
    println("Hello");
    super.read()
}
}
val t = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello".getBytes()) with Buffering
```

Comment: dreamlab (it's answered by hyunjl).

Comment: Choosen this as, the book's question was "In java io library, you add buffering to an inputstream with BuffredInputStream decorator. Reimplement buffering as a trait. For simplicity override the read method.

Comment: I found another way to make access applicable to override the inputstream. But does not seem to be one being discussed.

import java.io._

trait Buffering{
 val in:InputStream;
 //all the yada,yada
 def read()=
 {
  println("hello");
  in.read();
 }
}

val t = new {
 val in = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello".getBytes());
 } with Buffering

this way there is more control over the parameter. I'm still new in scala and trying to share what i had learned.

Comment: First, you do not answer the question. Second,  in your solution no buffering. See [this code](https://github.com/hempalex/scala-impatient/blob/master/Chapter10/08.scala) and [pull request](https://github.com/rustyconover/scala-impatient/commit/3b4cb0b04045218f1930bc3c3edfa1f0b8ddce06)

Answer (score 0):

I have been going through "Scala for the Impatient". Here is what I have  as a solution to exercise 8 in chapter 10:

```
import java.io._

object BufferedInputStream extends App {

  trait Buffering {
    this: FileInputStream =>
    val br = new BufferedInputStream(this)
  }

  def bufferedReader(f: String): Unit = {
    val fis = new FileInputStream(f) with Buffering
    var c = 0
    var blen = 8192
    var len = 0
    var b = new Array[Byte](blen)
    while (fis.br.available > 0) {
      if (fis.br.available > blen) len = blen
      else len = fis.br.available
      c = fis.br.read(b, 0, len)
      if (c == -1) return
      print((for (i <- 0 to (c - 1)) yield b(i).toChar).mkString)
    }
    fis.br.close
    fis.close
  }

  bufferedReader("webpagexample")

}
```