# Scala trait, superclass and early definition syntax

Tags: scala, inheritance, buffer, inputstream, traits

I'm learning Scala by working the exercises from the book "Scala for the Impatient". One exercise asks that:

> In the `java.io` library, you add buffering to an input stream with a
>   `BufferedInputStream` decorator. Reimplement buffering as a trait. For
>   simplicity, override the `read` method.

Even though it isn't clear (to me) which `read` method I should override (in the newly created trait or in the input stream), I came up with the following:

```
trait Buffered {
  self: InputStream =>

  val bufferSize: Int = 1024
  val buff = new Array[Byte](bufferSize)

  /* Number of bytes read so far */
  var pos = 0
  /* Number of bytes stored in the buffer */
  var count = -1

  private def fill() = {
    self.read(buff)
  }

  def readBuffered(): Int = {
    if (isAvailableInBuffer) {
      println("Data available in buffer.")
      incrementAndGet()
    } else {
      println("Data not available in buffer.")
      count = fill()

      println(f"Read $count%d bytes into buffer.")

      if (isAvailableInBuffer) incrementAndGet() else count
    }
  }

  private def isAvailableInBuffer = {
    count > (pos % bufferSize)
  }

  private def incrementAndGet() = {
    val x = buff(pos % bufferSize)

    pos += 1

    x
  }
}

class MyBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream, val size: Int) extends InputStream with Buffered {
  override def read() = {
    input.read()
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. How do I specify an early definition for `val bufferSize` in class `MyBufferedInputStream`? All examples online show early definition with a single trait, not with multiple classes and traits.
2. Does this look like a correct approach to what the question is asking for?

**Edit:**
Based on Kulu Limpa's answer, I modified my code. Following is what works (ignore the log stuff):

```
trait Buffered extends Logged { 

  self: InputStream =>

  val bufferSize: Int = 1024
  val buff = new Array[Byte](bufferSize)

  /* Number of bytes read so far */
  var pos = 0
  /* Number of bytes stored in the buffer */
  var count = 0

  def readBuffered(): Int = {
    if (isTimeToRefillBuffer) {
      log(f"Time to refill buffer. bufferSize = $bufferSize%d, pos = $pos%d, count = $count%d")
      count = fill()
    }

    if (isDataAvailableInbuffer) {
      log(f"Data available in buffer. bufferSize = $bufferSize%d, pos = $pos%d, count = $count%d")
      getFromBuffer()
    } else -1
  }

  /* Invoke the read method of the InputStream it'll be mixed in with */
  private def fill() = self.read(buff)

  private def isDataAvailableInbuffer = count > 0

  private def isTimeToRefillBuffer = !isDataAvailableInbuffer

  private def getFromBuffer() = {
    val x = buff(pos % bufferSize)

    pos += 1
    count -= 1

    x
  }
}

class MyBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream, override val bufferSize: Int) extends InputStream with Buffered {
  override def read() = {
    input.read()
  }
}
```

Test:

```
class MyBufferedInputStreamSpec extends UnitSpec {  

"Buffer size" should "be overridable and 4" in {
    new MyBufferedInputStream(newInputStream("abc"), 4).bufferSize should be(4)
  }

  "Buffered Stream" should "read data twice into buffer when bufferSize is smaller than number of bytes available" in {
    val str = new MyBufferedInputStream(newInputStream("abc"), 2) with ConsoleLogger with TimestampLogger

    str.readBuffered() should be('a')
    str.readBuffered() should be('b')
    str.readBuffered() should be('c')
    str.readBuffered() should be(-1)
  }

  "Buffered Stream" should "read data once into buffer when bufferSize is larger than number of bytes available" in {
    val str = new MyBufferedInputStream(newInputStream("abc"), 4) with ConsoleLogger with TimestampLogger

    str.readBuffered() should be('a')
    str.readBuffered() should be('b')
    str.readBuffered() should be('c')
    str.readBuffered() should be(-1)
  }

  private def newInputStream(str: String) = {
    new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(UTF_8))
  }
}
```

Comment: I put up a solution to this exercise at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169016/stackoverflow-when-use-bufferedinputstream-as-a-trait-in-scala/29587949#29587949

Comment: @jmaschad objects mixing in `Buffered` will HAVE to be subclasses of `InputStream` to compile, that's why the self reference is there for.

Comment: @TrisNefzger I see your solution but I want to develop my own. The solution isn't the goal, learning is. I'm still looking for an answer to my q1 above.

Comment: @abhijit-sarkar you're absolutely right of course. What I really wanted to say is that `Buffered` is not a subclass of `InputStream`. So depending on your use case you will not be able to call methods expecting an `InputStream` without a cast or depend on variance for subclassing etc.

Comment: What is your question about exactly, i.e. "Should I choose either place for redefinition because of ..."?:
 1. Efficiency, style, maintainablity, ...
 2. Subject of exercise
 3. Correctness of some using pattern

Comment: @Odomontois What I'm looking for is the syntax to use early definition with a constructor argument. See my response to 'Kulu Limpa' below.
I'm also looking for suggestions from Scala developers who've more experience than me with the language (which's everybody) if the above looks like a correct Scala approach or idiom. There's code that works and there's code that follows a language idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

The syntax for implementing a class with pre-initialized fields is

```
class ImplementingClass extends {val field1 = ???; val field2 = ???} with AbstractSuperclass with Trait1 with Trait2
```

Note that, despite the keyword `with`, the (abstract) superclass needs to be at the first position and you cannot extend multiple classes.

In the example,

```
class MyBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream, size: Int) extends {val bufferSize: Int = size} with InputStream with Buffered
```

works, but making `bufferSize` a constructor argument is in this case more readable

```
class MyBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream, val bufferSize: Int) extends InputStream with Buffered
```

---

> How do I specify an early definition for `val bufferSize` in class `MyBufferedInputStream`? All examples online show early definition with a single trait, not with multiple classes and traits.

I do not think there is a difference in early definition - or "Pre-initialized fields" as it is called in [Chapter 20.5 in Programming in Scala, First Edition](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html) - based on the number of traits you mix in. But let us go through the example:

Let us assume you didn't initialize `bufferSize` in `Buffered`, i.e.,

```
trait Buffered {
  self: InputStream =>

  val bufferSize: Int
  val buff = new Array[Byte](bufferSize)
  /* ... */
}
```

First, the wrong way to implement a buffered input stream:

```
class WrongBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream) extends InputStream with Buffered {
  val bufferSize = 1024
  override def read() = input.read()
}
```

Because the fields of the superclass, i.e., `Buffered.buff` are initialized before the fields of the subclass, `new Array[Byte](bufferSize)` is called before `bufferSize` is initialized, hence when `bufferSize` is `0`, leading to a buffer of length zero.

There are multiple solutions to this problem:

- make `bufferSize` in the implementing class a `lazy val` so it is initialized on the first use
- use a pre-initialized field
- make `bufferSize` a constructor argument

Code:

```
class MyBufferedInputStreamLazyInitialization(val input: InputStream) extends InputStream with Buffered {
  lazy val bufferSize = 1024
  override def read() = input.read()
}

class MyBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream) extends {val bufferSize: Int = 1024} with InputStream with Buffered {
  override def read() = input.read()
}

class MyBufferedInputStreamWithCustomSize(val input: InputStream, val bufferSize: Int = 1024) extends InputStream with Buffered {
  override def read() = input.read()
}
```

Example usage:

```
println(new WrongBufferedInputStream(System.in).buff.length)                 // 0
println(new MyBufferedInputStreamLazyInitialization(System.in).buff.length)  // 1024
println(new MyBufferedInputStream(System.in).buff.length)                    // 1024
println(new MyBufferedInputStreamWithCustomSize(System.in).buff.length)      // 1024
println(new MyBufferedInputStreamWithCustomSize(System.in, 512).buff.length) // 512
```

> Does this look like a correct approach to what the question is asking for?

I do not own a copy of *Scala for the Impatient*, but the approach looks good to me.

Thanks to the self-type you can inject any `InputStream` and create, e.g., a buffered file input stream:

```
class BufferedFileInputStream(file: File) extends {val bufferSize = 1024} with FileInputStream(file) with Buffered
```

You can also create other decorators of `InputStream` and mix them in, e.g.,

```
trait Awesomeness {
  self: InputStream =>
  /* add some awesome functionality */
}

class BufferedAwesomeInputStream(val input: InputStream) extends {val bufferSize = 1024} with InputStream with Buffered with Awesomeness {
  override def read() = input.read()
}
```

While the approach looks good, the specific implementation is a bit odd. For example, `readBuffered` returns either the buffered value at the current position, or the number of bytes stored in the buffer, which coincidentally can both be seen as an `Int` but are conceptually different. Also, exposing the `var` fields and the mutable array `buff` in the public interface is dangerous as this gives client code the ability to mutate the internal state of `Buffered`.

I understand that `InputStream.read()` returns the "code" `-1` if the end of stream is reached. Nevertheless, a more idiomatic `readBuffered()` implementation would return an `Option[Byte]`, returning `None` if there is no data available in the buffer:

```
def readBuffered(): Option[Byte] = {
  if (isAvailableInBuffer) {
    Some(incrementAndGet())
  } else {
    count = fill()
    if (isAvailableInBuffer) Some(incrementAndGet()) else None
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
val f = new MyBufferedInputStream(new InputStream {
  val data = "hello" map (_.toByte)
  var pos = 0
  override def read(): Int = if (pos < data.length){pos = pos + 1; data(pos - 1).asInstanceOf[Int]} else -1
}, 1024)
println(f.readBuffered() map (_.asInstanceOf[Char])) // Some(h)
println(f.readBuffered() map (_.asInstanceOf[Char])) // Some(e)
println(f.readBuffered() map (_.asInstanceOf[Char])) // Some(l)
println(f.readBuffered() map (_.asInstanceOf[Char])) // Some(l)
println(f.readBuffered() map (_.asInstanceOf[Char])) // Some(o)
println(f.readBuffered() map (_.asInstanceOf[Char])) // None
```

Comment: I think what I was looking for is indirectly answered in your response. With an early definition like the following, `extends InputStream` becomes `with InputStream`. Does this look right (note the early definition referring to a constructor argument)
`class MyBufferedInputStream(val input: InputStream, val size: Int) extends { val bufferSize = size } with InputStream with Buffered {`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes, this works, but I think in this case you would make `bufferSize` directly a constructor argument instead of defining the alias `size`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Unfortunately, I did only understand that your first question was purely about syntax when you wrote this in your comment (although I should have realized it as it is already written in the title). Is the information between the two quotes (i.e., the four ways to define `bufferSize`) useful at all, or do you suggest I delete this part from my answer?